# Loading Big Cartel JSON object in to external PHP

Tags: json, wordpress, bigcartel

We're fairly inexperience with JSON and are having trouble displaying an object from a JSON string from a Big Cartel store in to our WordPress site.

So, if on our Big Cartel site, we load the following URL (which is just the link to the store's cart location with *.json* on the end):

e.g. **ourstore.com/cart.json**

We get the following string of variables:

> {"items":[{"id":59269479,"name":"Test 4","price":"8.0","unit_price":"4.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"4.0","quantity":2,"product":"test-4","option":59269479},{"id":59269434,"name":"Test 2","price":"2.0","unit_price":"1.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"1.0","quantity":2,"product":"test-2","option":59269434},{"id":59271363,"name":"Test 6","price":"544.0","unit_price":"544.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"544.0","quantity":1,"product":"test-6","option":59271363}],"item_count":5,"price":"554.0","total":"554.0"}

From that string, we're basically just trying to display the `"item_count":5` variable in to the external WordPress site.

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the javascript API you're trying to use on your external Wordpress site won't work with shopping cart data -- the Cart information can only be displayed directly in a Big Cartel store. More information on that is here: http://help.bigcartel.com/customer/portal/articles/772751-javascript-ajax

You can use our API to display other store and product information on your website though, more details and a brief tutorial are here: http://help.bigcartel.com/customer/portal/articles/772771-api

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in javascript.

```
var jsonString = '{"items":[{"id":59269479,"name":"Test 4","price":"8.0","unit_price":"4.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"4.0","quantity":2,"product":"test-4","option":59269479},{"id":59269434,"name":"Test 2","price":"2.0","unit_price":"1.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"1.0","quantity":2,"product":"test-2","option":59269434},{"id":59271363,"name":"Test 6","price":"544.0","unit_price":"544.0","shipping":0.0,"tax":0.0,"total":"544.0","quantity":1,"product":"test-6","option":59271363}],"item_count":5,"price":"554.0","total":"554.0"}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Now just use the following line in the place where you want to display

```
jsonObj.item_count
```

Comment: Thanks for your response dileep, nothing's displaying when I try this though. Does 'jsonObj.item_count' need to be wrapped in anything other than <script></script>? or does it also need some sort of write or print function with it? (additionally, it we're loading the json from a dynamic url, do we just replace the json variables above with the URL?

Comment: Can you provide the code how you are getting this json

Comment: I changed it to use the following method, which seems to be working:

`<span id="bagcount"></span>
<script>
var JSONObject = {"items":[],"item_count":5,"price":0,"total":0};
document.getElementById("bagcount").innerHTML=JSONObject.item_count;
</script>`

But the only thing is we need the JSONObject to dynamically load: http://store.nuswimwear.com/cart.json

Comment: Are you using the jquery

Comment: I think this will help you
jQuery.getJSON( "http://store.nuswimwear.com/cart.json", function( data ) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
    document.getElementById("bagcount").innerHTML=jsonObject.item_count
});

Comment: Are you using the jquery